# What is the difference between dhcp3-server and isc-dhcp-server packages?

Tags: dhcp

What is the difference between dhcp3-server and isc-dhcp-server packages in ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on these links:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp

```
dhcp3-client: ISC DHCP server (transitional package)
dhcp3-common: ISC DHCP common files (transitional package)
dhcp3-dev: ISC DHCP development files (transitional package)
dhcp3-relay: ISC DHCP relay (transitional package)
dhcp3-server: ISC DHCP server **(transitional package)**
isc-dhcp-client: ISC DHCP client
isc-dhcp-client-dbg: ISC DHCP client (debugging symbols)
isc-dhcp-client-udeb: ISC DHCP Client for debian-installer
isc-dhcp-common: common files used by all the isc-dhcp* packages
isc-dhcp-dev: API for accessing and modifying the DHCP server and client state
isc-dhcp-relay: ISC DHCP relay daemon
isc-dhcp-relay-dbg: DHCP relay daemon (debugging symbols)
**isc-dhcp-server: ISC DHCP server for automatic IP address assignment**
isc-dhcp-server-dbg: ISC DHCP server for automatic IP address assignment (debug)
isc-dhcp-server-ldap: DHCP server able to use LDAP as backend
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ltsp/+bug/934014

ltsp-server still Suggests and ltsp-server-standalone still Recommends the old DHCP3 server. **Those dependencies need to be upgraded to instead use isc-dhcp-server.**

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dhcp3-server

squeeze (stable) (net): ISC DHCP server (transitional package)
4.1.1-P1-15+squeeze8 [security]: all
**also provided by: isc-dhcp-server**

it seems that isc-dhcp-server is newer, and replaces dhcp3